# What are the methods to ask user continue to fill the missing information contact

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I installed Facebook Omniauth Sign Up and When I can subscribe no informations are stocked in my computer. I wanna asked people complete the subscribe to send directly user at a contact form to fill complementary information.

I don't know the method to do this do I just call the right link?

Thank you for your answer.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZaP3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its calling `validation` check the link below

in your model `validates :name, presence: true`

more info [validation in rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Comment: Ok I understand it thnak you but when I use devise wit Facebook Sign In I can't keep data. I want to redirect user to a form when they subscribe wit facebook.

Comment: @BaptisteBecmeur check this link may be will helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373640/omniauth-facebook-redirects-to-registration-screen-instead-of-creating-user